# Social Framework requires Facebook App ID?

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, social-framework

In the past with Facebook-ios-sdk I need to create an App ID on Facebook site to post within the iOS app. But now, with social framework the post works even without app ID...

It's right ? Or it's possible to set app ID even in social framework ?

The problem is that now all your post sended with social framework report the label "... from iOS". But if I want the previous behavior "From my app-name" ?

Thanks

Comment: I thought it was a valid question. OP is asking about a way to integrate facebook app id into ios 6 social framework.

Comment: For me its a valid question... Anyway, did you find an answer?